# Trigger на вставку записи

Tags: oracle, plsql

Доброго времени суток! Допустим есть таблица Otdel с первичным ключом ID_Otdel. Как правильно написать триггер на вставку записи, чтобы в триггере генерировался автоматически ID_Otdel? Помогите...

Comment: А почему именно триггер? Обычного сиквенса не хватает?

Comment: ну хотелось бы изучить триггеры, их работу.

Comment: про сиквенс поподробнее если можно тоже...

Comment: <http://www.firststeps.ru/sql/oracle/r.php?112>

<https://www.google.ru/search?q=Триггеры+oracle&oq=Триггеры+oracle>

:-)

Ищите и найдёте.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашел решение:

```
create table Otdel (
    id_otdel number(38)
  , code varchar2(16)
  , constraint pk_test primary key (id_otdel)
);

create or replace trigger tgr_otdel
before insert or update on otdel
for each row
begin
   if :new.id_otdel is null then
     select sq_otdel.nextval into :new.id_otdel from dual;
   end if;
end;
/
-- Использование последовательности напрямую.
insert into otdel (id_otdel, code) values (sq_otdel.nextval, 'One');
-- Определение значения первичного ключа в триггере.
insert into otdel (code) values ('Two');
insert into otdel (id_otdel, code) values (null, 'Three');
```

последовательность sq_otdel надо тоже создавать, если ее нет.